# Замена картинке при клике

Tags: javascript, html, css

Не подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно так реализовать смену картинок без обновления страницы? Желательно при кликах на любую миниатюру **(img2/3/4)** она меняется местами с **img1**, но можно и просто замета большой картинки при клике на миниатюрную картинку снизу.

[image: уот так уот]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.block{  
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 25px auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

[id^=s-]{
  display: none;
}
[id^=s-] + label{  
  margin-top: 310px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: #ccc;
}
[id^=s-]:checked + label{
  background: #f00;
}
[id^=s-] + label ~ [id^=block-content-]{
   display: none;
   position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
   margin-left: -150px;   
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;   
   line-height: 300px;
   background: #ccc;
   font-size: 50px;
}
#s-1:checked + label ~ #block-content-1,
#s-2:checked + label ~ #block-content-2,
#s-3:checked + label ~ #block-content-3{
  display: block; 
}
#s-2:checked + label,
#s-2:checked + label ~ #block-content-2{
  background: #FF7F50;
}
#s-3:checked + label,
#s-3:checked + label ~ #block-content-3{
  background: #008B8B;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <input type="radio" name="s" id="s-1" checked />
  <label for="s-1">1</label>  
  <div id="block-content-1">1</div>
  
  <input type="radio" name="s" id="s-2" />
  <label for="s-2">2</label>  
  <div id="block-content-2">2</div>
  
  <input type="radio" name="s" id="s-3" />
  <label for="s-3">3</label>  
  <div id="block-content-3">3</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете заменить картинку, например, с помощью:

```
 clickfunction() {
     d = new Date();
     $("#myimg").attr("src", "/myimg.jpg?"+d.getTime());
 }
```

---

Также подобная тема была на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745060/change-image-without-page-refresh-or-reload).

Вот решение для вас: **http://jsfiddle.net/nz8qy41y/9/**

```js
$('a').on('click', function(e){
    $('img').attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
li {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
a {
    display: block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 32px;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWMVJ.jpg?s=128&g=1&g&s=16" />
<ul>
    <li><a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWMVJ.jpg?s=128&g=1&g&s=16">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://is2.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple7/v4/44/1a/5d/441a5d52-409a-083d-dfe7-dd51c43732ef/pr_source.png/100x100bb-85.jpg">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://img.scoop.it/ygxGkWUyk2twloZcnxTbnjl72eJkfbmt4t8yenImKBXEejxNn4ZJNZ2ss5Ku7Cxt">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://placekitten.com/g/350/300">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: И вам спасибо, но вы меня не так поняли!